FastAPI uvicorn starrlette gradio package errors
I am trying to upgrade a gradio app to the latest version. I have been able to get the app running again but it's throwing server errors when i go to the browser. I am getting the following errors listed:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gil/miniconda3/envs/diarize-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 399, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gil/miniconda3/envs/diarize-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 70, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gil/miniconda3/envs/diarize-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 292, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/gil/miniconda3/envs/diarize-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    self.middleware_stack = self.build_middleware_stack()
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gil/miniconda3/envs/diarize-env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 213, in build_middleware_stack
    for cls, options in reversed(middleware):
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I am guessing that there is some package conflict that I am missing here. Has anyone updated to the lastest version fast API experienced similar issues?

Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example and a used dependency list with versions?

Hi, have you resolved this please?
